# CSS Keep Footer at Bottom with Expanding Content

Tags: css, html, footer

I am building a page [HERE](http://mew09040.classweb.ccv.edu/WebDevBA/Project/Lyrics.php) and I'm having trouble with the footer. I've done a lot of research looking at sticky footers and wrapping everything in containers... and my head is spinning.

The goal of the site is to display the song lyrics on the right as the title is clicked on the left, and it works miraculously well. The problem is that the footer doesn't move with the lyrics...

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Also, please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used `position:absolute` for any element then you must add to `position:relative` their parent element otherwise it not work.

```
body {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Or If you don't want add this in body then just wrap all the divs on one parent div like `.wrapper` and this css in that.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="banner"></div>
   <div class="container clearfix"></div>
   <footer></footer>
<div>
```

Also add `clearfix` class in `container` div because its have float element

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Is one of those methods better than the other?

Comment: I have prefer second method to wrap all divs in one parent div.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix or make a sticky footer by using `CSS` or you can just put this CSS for you `footer`.

```
.footer-class{
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 999;
}
```

- Position is fixed for footer will never move in any page.
- bottom 0 will fixed the footer at the bottom.
- left and right 0 will placed the footer in the screen.
- Width 100% will show the full width.
- z-index will show at the front. Placed everything will behind the footer.